# Using svmlight-style data with naive bayes classifier in mallet

Tags: java, svm

i have a couple of questions to ask
1) in svmlight-style data there is (target feature:value feature:value ...) 
i know what `feature` and `value` are but what is the `target`? what does it mean? I want to know this because i plan on making a text file with this data written to it.

2) also in one file there are multiple line of (target feature:value feature:value)
does each line represent one document? Lets say i have 50 documents, so each line would represent one document?

3) after i make this text file with the `svmlight-style` data stored in it, i want to pass it into the `Naive Bayes Classifier` in `MALLET`. How would this work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official SVMLight site, a training set consists of lines

```
<line> .=. <target> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <info>
```

where each line is defined as follows:

```
<target> .=. +1 | -1 | 0 | <float> 
<feature> .=. <integer> | "qid"
<value> .=. <float>
<info> .=. <string>
```

"In classification mode, the target value denotes the class of the example. +1 as the target value marks a positive example, -1 a negative example respectively. So, for example, the line

```
-1 1:0.43 3:0.12 9284:0.2 # abcdef
```

specifies a negative example for which feature number 1 has the value 0.43, feature number 3 has the value 0.12, feature number 9284 has the value 0.2, and all the other features have value 0. In addition, the string abcdef is stored with the vector, which can serve as a way of providing additional information for user defined kernels. A class label of 0 indicates that this example should be classified using transduction. The predictions for the examples classified by transduction are written to the file specified through the -l option. The order of the predictions is the same as in the training data. "

See the official site http://svmlight.joachims.org/ for details.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question, but I already found this out ;)